# ASP.NET MVC 2 Unit Testing Stange Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working through the book Professional ASP.NET MVC 2 and I am trying to get the unit testing in chapter 1 to work correctly; howver, I am getting some very strange errors.

There are two projects in the solution: NerdDinner, and NerdDinner.Tests.

In the NerdDinner Project I have the following interface:

IDinnerRepository.cs

```
//...
namespace NerdDinner.Models
{
     interface IDinnerRepository
     {
     //...
     }
}
```

Also in the NerdDinner project, I have the following class:

```
//...
using NerdDinner.Models;
//...
namespace NerdDinner.Controllers
{
     public class DinnersController : Controller
     {
     IDinnerRepository dinnerRepository;
     // Default constructor
     public DinnersController() : this(new DinnerRepository()){} // DinnerRepository is another concrete implementation of IDinnerRepository
     //Test constructor
     public DinnersController(IDinnerRepository repository) {
     dinnerRepository = repository;
     }
     }
}
```

In the NerdDinner.Tests project, I have the following concrete implementation of IDinnerRepository:

```
//...
using NerdDinner.Models;
//...
namespace NerdDinner.Tests.Fakes
{
     class FakeDinnerRepository : IDinnerRepository
     {
     //...
          public FakeDinnerRepository(List<Dinner> dinners)
          {
          //...
          }
     //...
     }
}
```

Now for the actual unit test (in NerdDinner.Tests)

```
using NerdDinner.Controllers;
//...
using NerdDinner.Models;
using NerdDinner.Tests.Fakes;
namespace NerdDinner.Tests
{
     [TestClass]
     public class DinnersControllerTest
     {
          List<Dinner> CreateTestDinners()
          {
          //...
          }
          DinnersController CreateDinnersController()
          {
          return new DinnersController(new FakeDinnerRepository(CreateTestDinners()));
          }
     }
}
```

And now for the actual problem:
In the method CreateDinnersController in the class DinnerControllerClass, I am getting the following error:

> DinnersController.DinnersController(NerdDinner.Models.IDinnerRepository repository) (+ 1 overload(s))
>   Error:
>   The best overloaded method match for 'NerdDinner.Controllers.DinnersController.DinnersController(NerdDinner.Models.IDinnerRepository)' has some invalid arguments.

It gives me the option to create a constructor stub in DinnersController. It generates the following code:

```
private global::NerdDinner.Tests.Fakes.FakeDinnerRepository repository;
//...
public DinnersController(global::NerdDinner.Tests.Fakes.FakeDinnerRepository repository)
{
     // TODO: Complete member initialization
     this.repository = repository;
}
```

Even after generating that code, I still get the same error. But why should I even need that code anyway? As far as I can tell, I am doing everything correctly.

Can anybody help me figure out what is going on here?

**Edit**
The generated code is giving the following error:

> The type or namespace 'Tests' does not exist in the namespace 'NerdDinner' (are you missing any assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've shown the `IDinnerRepository` interface is **not** public meaning that it is not visible from your unit test. I would recommend you making it public as I suspect you have two different interfaces : one defined in the unit test and one in your project which conflict. Also I would recommend you to avoid relying on Visual Studio generate all the crap reflection code in order to test private and internal members.

Comment: I made the interface public but I am still getting the same error.

Correction: The error is not longer there. Thanks!

Comment: @KPthunder: If the interface wasn't public before, how were you managing to implement it in your test project? That's why I suggested to check where the "go to definition" would take you...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I just typed out the code and it worked. The IDE was putting in the methods for me after I typed the name of the interface. I don't currently have resharper installed on this computer, do you think resharper would have found this?

Comment: @KPthunder: I'm not sure, but you should take note of what the IDE is doing for you - the interface must have got into the test project *somehow*, and you should be very wary of that.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I don't think the interface is in the test project though, because when I pressed F12 when it wasn't public it brought me to the interface in the non-test project.

Answer (score 0):

The last error you're getting is due to there being no reference from the production code to the test code - but that's appropriate. You don't want that extra constructor.

Instead, you need to find out why the existing constructor taking an `IDinnerRepository` isn't being used. Are you sure you only have one interface called `IDinnerRepository`? If you go to the `FakeDinnerRepository` source, go to the declaration, put the cursor in `IDinnerRepository` and hit F12 (go to definition) does it go to the right place?

If you add a new member to `IDinnerRepository` (just for the sake of testing: `void Foo();` would be fine) does it cause both the production and fake implementation to fail to compile?

Comment: Yes, F12 took me to the one IDinnerRepository in NerdDinner.Models. When I added void foo(), it forced to me to all that method to all concrete implementations.